# Perl syntax error in a while loop

Tags: perl, syntax

I think it is a very simple question but I don't know what is wrong with this code:

```
$seq = "";
$seqlength = length($seq);
$count = 0
while ($line = <>) {
  if (/^>/) {
    $count = 1;
    next; }
  if ($count == 1) {
    chomp;
    $seq .= $line; }
  last if eof(); }
```

It throws wrong syntax in lines 1, 3 and 6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you executing it? The syntax error is probably from the shell. If so, try adding `#!/usr/bin/env perl` as the very first line.

Comment: You are reading into `$line` but (implicitly) comparing against `$_`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo.

Comment: always put `;`!!! Perl != Python :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon.  Change:

```
$count = 0
```

to:

```
$count = 0;
```

Also, you likely meant:

```
  if ($line =~ /^>/) {
```

`use warnings;` helped me find that one.  And `chomp $line;`, too.